# Animated object showing up twice using wow.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, animate.css

I build a website homepage and animated it using wow. js (http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/), one of the divs that I have animated is a twitter feed. The issue is that the twitter feed pre-loads before the animation and then loads again together with animation. Is there a way to stop this from happening? (To me this is very odd since it didn't happen in the local install of the website and I have no idea what is causing it).

I wanst able to replicate this issue in js fiddle so here is the URL http://qeprize.org/ (its right at the bottom)

Answer (score 6):

Adding this to your css should solve that issue:

```
 .wow {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the iframe inside the #twitter_feed has an inline style set to visibility:visible.
Since you don't show your code, it's hard to tell where this comes from, it's probably done automatically by twitter's script.
You can try this :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var f = document.getElementById('twitter_feed');
    f.querySelector('iframe').style.visibility = "";
}
```